# Creating subplots using matplotlib using ordered data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

I have a data frame that looks like

```
d = {'First': ['A','A','A','B','B','C'], 
      'Second': ['B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A']
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

I want to be able to create bar graphs for each value in First, preferably using subplots, that  shows the number of values in second. I have tried using `df.groupby('First')['Second'].agg('value_counts').plot(kind = 'bar, subplots = True)` however this only produces a single graph. If possible I would also like to make the graph showcase percentage of the group or ordered by alphabetically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.groupby('First')['Second']\
  .agg('value_counts')\
  .unstack('First')\
  .plot.bar(subplots=True, figsize=(10,8))
```

Output:

[image]

The key is to unstack the columns which you want subplots to represent.  Each column in the dataframe should generate a subplot.

Comment: Thank you for informing me about the unstack option.

Comment: @Panic_Picnic You're welcome.  Happy coding.  Be safe and stay healthy.